# Neural Network with ordered categorical output

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, discrete-data

We tried to predict valuef for univariate time series. Sometimes they trend. Firstly we calculated 6 levels: 3 up and 3 down. Values for tending occur for some levels. These levels can be understood as a value's borders for some time. Our purpose is to predict what levels will be reached. When sent to a neural network the position of value among the levels and with some different additional information, how can we get an output? Is it a classification? What should be used: NN or decision trees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a network with thermometer coding. Specifically, 5 output neurons with $(0,0,0,0,0)$ for the first category, $(0,0,0,0,1)$ for the second one,... $(1,1,1,1,1)$ for the sixth one.

This coding is to be used also for training.

The thermometer coding is a well-established approach in the field, see e.g. http://www.archipel.uqam.ca/133/1/harnad91.cpnets.html

The result may be not crisp and some thresholding will be needed. For that purpose, one can go from left to right and accept the first item exceeding a given threshold. The value of the threshold can be found experimentally, testing values such as $0.1, 0.2 \dots 0.9$ and evaluating them e.g. by means of cross validation.

Comment: But in the training dataset there are observations with output like (00001), i.e. containg only 0 and 1. But using network we will receive vector of numbers from the interval (0,1). How can I find a theshold to tranform for example (0.1 0.6 0.8) to (0 0 1) or (0 1 1). What of these transformations is correct?

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.